# Descargar Imagen via laravel

Tags: laravel, imagen, descarga

Buenas quisiera descargar el archivo o imagen subida pero me aparece error de variable:

> Undefined variable: img_p_circulacion (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fenix\resources\views\Vehiculos\index.blade.php)

alguien sabe cual es el error adjunto codigo:

HTML

```html
                <tbody>
                 @foreach($listvehiculos as $listado)
                  <tr>
        <td>{{$listado['id']}}</td>
        <td>{{$listado['patente'] }}</td>
        <td>{{$listado['r_tecnica'] }}</td>
        <td>{{$listado['p_circulacion'] }}</td>
        <td>{{$listado['descripcion'] }}</td>
        <td>
         <a href="vehiculos/{{ $img_p_circulacion }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
         </a>
        </td>

        <td> 
         <form method="POST" action="{{action('vehiculosController@destroy', $listado->id)}}" >
          {{csrf_field()}}
          <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('¿Esta Seguro?')" >
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>
         </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
                 @endforeach
```

CONTROLADOR

```js
public function downloadFile($img_p_circulacion)
 {
  $pathtoFile = public_path().'images_circulacion/'.$img_p_circulacion;
  return response()->download($pathtoFile);
 }
```

ROUTE

```js
Route::resource('vehiculos', 'vehiculosController');

Route::get('/vehiculos/{img_p_circulacion}' , 'vehiculosController@downloadFile');
```

Comment: ¿como le pasas la variable `$img_p_circulacion` a la vista `Vehiculos/index.blade.php`?

Comment: lo tengo asi, para que pase todo, pero no especificamente img_p_circulacion

Comment: $listvehiculos = Vehiculos::all();
return view('Vehiculos.index',compact('listvehiculos'));

Comment: ¿ entonces `img_p_circulacion`es un campo del objeto `Vehiculos`? por favor, agrega a la pregunta el método que devuelve la vista `Vehiculos/index.blade.php` y si en la vista usas un `@foreach` para iterar sobre una colección, también agrega eso.

Comment: si, img_p_circulacion es un campo de la tabla vehiculos, lo cual esos campos los veo con un foreach

Comment: ok, entonces depende de como estés haciendo el @foreach. El error te dice que la variable `$img_p_circulacion` no está definida.

Comment: hay edite y muestro el foreach

Comment: ya lo hice amigo! gracias por tu ayuda, estaba escribiendo mal unas cosas, envio el codigo como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCION

```js
    public function show($img_p_circulacion)
    {
        $pathtoFile = public_path().'/images_circulacion/'.$img_p_circulacion;
        return response()->download($pathtoFile);
    }
```

```html
<a href="vehiculos/{{ $listado->img_p_circulacion }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
          </a>
```